# mysql error while running join query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT `register`.`first_name`, `register`.`last_name` 
JOIN `register` 
  ON `like_check`.`user` = `register`.`id` 
WHERE `like_check`.`look` = '31'
```

I am using above given query and I am getting error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN `register` ON `like_check`.`user` = `register`.`id` WHERE `like_check`.`loo'

```
like_check:-
id | user | look


register:-
id | first_name | last_name | email
```

Can anybody help me to solve this.

Comment: just read it carefully... it's SO obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what it should be. You are missing the `from` clause.

```
    SELECT 
   `register`.`first_name`, 
   `register`.`last_name` 
    from register
    JOIN `like_check` ON `like_check`.`user` = `register`.`id` 
    WHERE `like_check`.`look` = '31'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `from` clause:

```
SELECT `register`.`first_name`, `register`.`last_name` 
FROM    `like_check`
JOIN    `register` ON `like_check`.`user` = `register`.`id` 
WHERE `like_check`.`look` = '31'
```